# Most of my model disappears after using remesh

Tags: modeling, modifiers

When I apply a remesh modifier to this object, most of it disappears and it turns into this weird thing that is definitely not what I wanted.

In the preview of the modifier before applying, it looks fine as expected, it's only after applying that this happens.

So far I have tried:

1. applying all transformations
2. adding volume to mesh (my entire model disappeared after using the modifier)
3. changing the octree depth (that's only an option in the smooth, not voxel, so it doesn't work)

before:[image]

after: [image]

also my modifiers in case anyone wants to look
[image]

Comment: Have you tried applying the mirror modifier before the remesh?

Comment: Hi, @Autumn.. this does look like a duplicate. If for any reason the other answer isn't working for you, edit to point out why, and we can re-open for you.